# How to save StreamedResponse of audio to file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, wav, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download an Azure Blob, which is a WAV file. I used [azblob](https://pub.dev/packages/azblob) package to download the file and it returns a Streamed Response.

This is what I've done so far.

```
// Download WAV file from Azure's Blob Storage Container
var file = await storage.getBlob(wavFileLink);

print(file);
```

This is what Debug Console shows for `print(file)`.

[image]

How do I save the StreamedResponse to WAV File in Flutter? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the data as byte data with the following code:

```dart
var file = await storage.getBlob(wavFileLink);
Uint8List data = await file.stream.toBytes();
```

If you really want to save the data as a file, you'll need to use the `path_provider` package:

```YAML
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
```

```dart
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

//Obtain the directory you want. This is application documents.
var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var sysFile = File('${dir.path}/file.wav');
sysFile.writeAsBytes(data);
```

Comment: I've tried your answer but the wav file is not playable. I used the [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package to play the wav file.

Comment: @ariessa That's a separate issue for a separate question. You asked how to store your data as a file, and I believe this answer does that completely. If you have further issues down the line, ask another question.

Comment: My bad. Thank you for your fast response.